# attempetd to dived by zero print crystal reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I Have one Project in VB.net i Print Barcode Label, But I have one Problem I can't Solve, When I show Reports In ReportViewer work FINE but when i try to PRINT display this ERROR "attempted to divide by zero" "Crystal Report Windows Form Viewer"

I don't have any formula in Report just Parameters!

```
Try
        If listView1.CheckedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Dim Condition As String = ""
            Dim Condition1 As String = ""
            For I = 0 To listView1.CheckedItems.Count - 1
                Condition += String.Format("'{0}',", listView1.CheckedItems(I).Text)
                Condition1 += String.Format("'{0}',", listView1.CheckedItems(I).SubItems(3).Text)
            Next
            Condition = Condition.Substring(0, Condition.Length - 1)
            Condition1 = Condition1.Substring(0, Condition1.Length - 1)
            Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
            Timer1.Enabled = True
            con = New SqlConnection(cs)
            con.Open()
            Dim st As String = "Select Barcode,Productname,(SalesPrice) as SalesRate from Product where ProductCode in (" & Condition & ") "
            For j As Integer = 1 To Int32.Parse(Val(txtNoOfCopies.Text)) - 1
                st = st & "Union all Select Barcode,Productname,(SalesPrice) as SalesRate from Product where ProductCode in (" & Condition & ")"
            Next
            cmd = New SqlCommand(st, con)
            adp = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            dtable = New DataTable()
            adp.Fill(dtable)
            con.Close()
            ds = New DataSet()
            ds.Tables.Add(dtable)
            ds.WriteXmlSchema("BarcodeLabelPrinting1.xml")
            Dim rpt As New rptBarcodeLabelPrinting1
            rpt.SetDataSource(ds)
            rpt.SetParameterValue("p1", txtCompany.Text)
            rpt.SetParameterValue("p2", txtCurrencyCode.Text)
            frmReport.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
            frmReport.ShowDialog()
            rpt.Close()
            rpt.Dispose()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.[Error])
    End Try
```

Comment: Do you have any more details on the exception such as call stack you could edit into your question?  Being able to preview but not print suggests to me that the report itself is fine, so might be something in either the printer driver or internal to Crystal report engine

Comment: If I add this line before report privue "report.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0)" its work but after the display report I'cont Print.

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the error?